# How to validate dynamic api response in groovy

Tags: groovy, katalon-studio, web-api-testing

My API response has many fields but those fields repeat. The issue is that they change their locations. So I cannot use the locators.I am using excel to compare data.

Whenever there is change in data I should only update the excel and not the code.

```
{
    "mobilePlans": [
        {
            "offerId": "67d33e0e-4225-426b-ad56-68e39be577e4",
            "product": {
                "promotionReferences": [
                    {
                        "promoId": "2074e0c0-08b6-49ea-8ea9-9390651ab676"
                    }
                ],
                "source": "cpopC1",
                "lobType": "wireless"
            }
        },
        {
            "offerId": "ff1f96e8-704e-4d97-92c6-35008ec1c0ac",
            "product": {
                "promotionReferences": [
                    {
                        "promoId": "2074e0c0-08b6-49ea-8ea9-9390651ab676"
                    }
                ],
                "source": "cpopC1",
                "lobType": "wireless"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Give us an example how the response looks like.

Comment: @Catalin-Added. The issue the data is dynamic using the locators doe not help.

Comment: Ok so now we have a sample response (still not formatted as a code block but still, we have something) but you haven't told us what you are trying to validate in that response. Please provide specifics.Also assuming your data is json, it's broken. There are extra commas in there, the braces are not closed etc etc. I took the liberty of reformatting your data. Please validate that it looks as it should and provide specifics on what you are trying to do.